# How to get type form TBAA metadata node (MDNode) [llvm 7.0]

Tags: llvm

Now, I want to use a LLVM pass, which belongs to LLVM 3.3. In the source code, They get the type from MDNode as following:

```
Type *ElTy = UTBAATag->getOperand(i)->getType();
```

However, I got the following error:

‘class llvm::Metadata’ has no member named ‘getType’
         Type *ElTy = UTBAATag->getOperand(i)->getType()

For llvm 3.3, UTBAATag->getOperand(i) return a Value. However,
for llvm 7.0, UTBAATag->getOperand(i) return a MDOperand, which can be casted to MDString. I find the following words form LLVM Language Reference Manual:

"The root node of a TBAA type hierarchy is an MDNode with 0 operands or with exactly one MDString operand.
Scalar type descriptors are represented as an MDNode s with two operands. The first operand is an MDString denoting the name of the struct type. LLVM does not assign meaning to the value of this operand, it only cares about it being an MDString. The second operand is an MDNode which points to the parent for said scalar type descriptor, which is either another scalar type descriptor or the TBAA root. Scalar type descriptors can have an optional third argument, but that must be the constant integer zero."

We could get the "struct type" form MDString like this:

```
MDString *NodeName = dyn_cast<MDString>(MD->getOperand(0))
StringRef T = NodeName->getString()
```

Unfortunately, we get the "StringRef" type.
How could we get the "Tpye" type?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the function MetadataAsValue::get make sense. The following is an example:

```
NamedMDNode *UTBAA = M.getNamedMetadata("clang.tbaa.unions");
for (size_t i = 0, e = UTBAA->getNumOperands(); i != e; ++i) {
  MDNode *MD = UTBAA->getOperand(i);
  MDNode *TBAATag = dyn_cast_or_null<MDNode>(MD->getOperand(1));
  Value *ValType = dyn_cast<Value>(MetadataAsValue::get(MD->getContext(), MD->getOperand(0))); 
  UnionsTBAA[cast<StructType>(ValType->getType())] = TBAATag;
}
```